# Why do links in the registration email not let one log in directly?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, email

See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21515853#21515853) for the context.

Let me explain my steps:

- I answered a question on Math Stack Exchange using the Guest option, by entering my email (call it `x@yz.com`).
- My browser crashed, I lost all the cookies.
- I couldn't access that account which was then left as an unregistered account. ([link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21516450#21516450))
- The email I received (for posting an answer) said 'Set Password' sort of thing.
- I clicked on that link and used the default Open ID they provide (I entered the email as `x@yz.com`).
- I got another email for verification of this account. It got verified and an account was created that started with one reputation while the unregistered one was at 10.
- Now to get to the lost one, I used the merge profiles option.
- Entered profile URLs, and I got two verification in the same inbox. (probably because `x@yz.com` was linked to both the profiles)
- Account got merged, all good.

Why couldn't "The email I received (for posting an answer) said 'Set Password' sort of thing." directly connect those two profiles?

What is the use of [getting two account merge verification emails](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21516586#21516586) to the same inbox and not allowing direct access from that Set Pasword link? (everything comes to one single inbox)

I think this is some sort of security measure which I am unable to make sense of. Can somebody explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Suppose someone intercepts your email? Now they have access to your account.

Comment: @Oded But the person who does so will also have to get into my inbox for the Account creation/OpenID verification. Bare with me if I am messing things up.

Comment: @Oded I think I have to change "login" from the title to "merge them" for my question to make sense.

Comment: Also, the normal use case is that people have two _different_ email addresses.

Comment: @Oded True. But why does one have to go till the merge step. That link should directly merge those profiles or rather directly work on that unregistered account.